# removing appstore android from the cloud

Tags: amazon-appstore

there has been discussion about this item in earlier years, but I want to know this: 
I want to reload the App Store because the apps I bought with it do not function any longer after I removed the App Store (because I did not plan on any further purchases via this store); reloading fails, probably because the version I tried to remove is not removed from the Cloud Library. It seems to me impossible to acces the Cloud-library. So: what to do?

Comment: Please explain the problem you are having with reinstalling the Amazon Appstore.  How does it fail?  What does it have to do with your cloud library?

Comment: Hi Matthew, when I just remove Amazon Appst, I do not have the result I aimed at; I cannot open the apps  I bought (appr 5 month ago). The message I keep on getting is: 'Amazon Appstore required. It looks like you no longer heve Amazone Appstore on your device. Please install an Amazon Appsore and sign in with your username and password to use this app. '

Comment: Right, so following those instructions you should reinstall the Amazon Appstore.  What happens when you do so?

Comment: In order to be able to re-install Amazone Appstore, I'll have to remove the old one complety, this will be clear.The idea about having to move the Amazon apstore app also from my cloudlibrary is a remark I red on one of the Amazon community sites.

Comment: Please tell us **what happens** when you try to reinstall it.  Not what you read, we need to know what it is actually doing on your device.  If you are having trouble finding where to install it from, you could get it from [here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/amazon-mobile-llc/appstore/appstore-release-20-0000-912-1c_650000010-release/amazon-appstore-release-20-0000-912-1c_650000010-android-apk-download/) or install their Underground app instead (which should work just as well) from [here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get-appstore/android).

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed payed apps from Amazon's store, they will need the corresponding Amazon app to work: it is used to verify their license. So if you uninstall the Amazon app, they no longer can do that – and thus refuse to work, as they assume you've got no valid license.

So you've few choices:

- re-install the Amazon app
- stop using those apps (uninstall them)
- uninstall those apps you've bought from Amazon, buy them again from another store you plan to keep, and re-install them from there.

Comment: Hi Izzy, this is a very sensible answer, I agree with you about the choices I have, but....my preferred scenario would be to re-install the Amazon app, what doesn't go, because I fail to uninstall the app that I used which I uninstalled, but seems not to be uninstalled in the Cloud! So if anybody could tell my how to uninstall an uninstalled app in the Cloud? but thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't now what you mean by "uninstall an app in the cloud"; but to re-install an app, if you have the `.apk` file, you can use `adb install -r <APK-file>` – which should replace the app even if it's fully installed, so it might help to re-establish it "over those dead bones". (Hm, "what doesn't go"? Feel free to explain in German, I'd offer the translation then. Maybe we are on the woodway, but equal goes it lose ;)